# Normal distribution test ( D'Agostino and Pearson's) in Scipy - results don't make sense

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, p-value, normality-assumption, scipy

I want to test if an array of numbers is approximately normally distributed.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import normaltest

N = 50
expon = scipy.stats.expon().rvs(size=N)
norm = scipy.stats.norm(loc=10, scale=1.5).rvs(size=N)
combined = np.concatenate((expon, norm))

print("Exponential distribution p-value:", normaltest(expon).pvalue)
print("Normal distribution p-value:", normaltest(norm).pvalue)
print("Combined distribution p-value:", normaltest(combined).pvalue)

>>> Exponential distribution p-value: 0.0016080772884856968
>>> Normal distribution p-value: 0.8918625222101648
>>> Combined distribution p-value: 0.9521781766658066
```

The first two numbers seem OK, however the third should also have p-value close to zero since it's obviously not normally distributed (it's a hybrid of 2 distributions). Why is this algorithm failing?

Comment: Could you please explain what `np.concatenate` actually does?  How do you know the algorithm is "failing"?

Answer (score 1):

The test you are using looks only at skewness and kurtosis; it will miss any deviations from normality (like, say bimodality) that are not also reflected in the skewness and kurtosis (bimodal distributions can have similar skewness and kurtosis to the normal).

The skewness of a 50-50 mix (not strictly a mixture but I'll leave this issue aside) of the normal you used and a standard exponential is much less than the skewness of the exponential itself, generally within the typical variation in skewness from the normal at that sample size.

The kurtosis of a mix like that is definitely on the low side, but not necessarily so low that it will always show up with this particular test at this sort of sample size.

It's not clear to me that anything has gone wrong. I am not especially surprised that it didn't detect that the kurtosis was too low. (This doesn't mean your code is correct, I have not attempted to check it -- simply that I don't find it automatically surprising that the p-value might not be low in a single sample which contains observations from both distributions.)